# Doctrine ORM - Event Subscriber that computes the values of "Child entities" and persist this values on another Entity

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I'm kind of confused on where should I implement the Event Subscriber (actually, I am not even sure if I should use Entity Listener instead).

So, I have this entity called `ServiceDoctrineEntity` and this entity has many storage devices:

```
class ServiceDoctrineEntity {

    /**
     * One Service has many storage devices.
     *
     * @OneToMany(targetEntity="ServiceStorageDevicesDoctrineEntity", mappedBy="service", cascade={"all"})
     * @OrderBy({"order" = "ASC"})
     * @var ServiceStorageDevicesDoctrineEntity $storage_devices Description.
     */
    private $storage_devices;
}
```

And each storage devices has its own "storage space/value"

```
class ServiceStorageDevicesDoctrineEntity {
    /**
     * @Column(type="bigint", nullable=true, options={"comment":"The normalised value, calculated from $amount * $unit."})
     * @var int $value The normalised value, calculated from $amount * $unit.
     */
    private $value;
}
```

My problem is, I should run a computation logic that will trigger everytime there's a change in the storage devices, (new storage device added/deleted, or storage space changed, etc).

1. I need to compute the total number of "storage devices" this service have.
2. Aggregate or Sum the total "values" of each of storage devices

These "summary" will be saved on an entity called: `ServiceStorageSummaryDoctrineEntity`

```
class ServiceStorageSummaryDoctrineEntity {

    /**
     * One Service Support type has One Service.
     *
     * @OneToOne(targetEntity="ServiceDoctrineEntity", inversedBy="storage_summary")
     * @JoinColumn(name="service_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $service;

    /**
     * @Column(type="bigint", nullable=true, options={"default":0, "comment":"The total value (normalised) of storage space."})
     * @var integer $total_value The total value (normalised) of storage space.
     */
    private $total_value;

    /**
     * @Column(type="integer", nullable=true, options={"default":0, "comment":"The total amount of storage devices."})
     * @var integer $device_count The total amount of storage devices.
     */
    private $device_count;

}
```

I tried to write an [`EventSubscriber`](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/events.html#implementing-event-listeners) class for this that listens on `onFlush` event:

```
class ServiceStorageDevicesEventListener implements EventSubscriber {

    /**
     * Returns an array of events this subscriber wants to listen to.
     *
     * @return string[]
     */
    public function getSubscribedEvents() {
        return array(
            Events::onFlush,
        );
    }

    public function onFlush( OnFlushEventArgs $eventArgs ) {
        $em  = $eventArgs->getEntityManager();
        $uow = $em->getUnitOfWork();

        foreach ( $uow->getScheduledEntityInsertions() as $entity ) {
            // Should I run the computation here?
            // Which entity should I be listening to? `ServiceDoctrineEntity` or `ServiceStorageSummaryDoctrineEntity`?
        }

        foreach ( $uow->getScheduledEntityUpdates() as $entity ) {
            // Should I run the computation here?
            // Which entity should I be listening to? `ServiceDoctrineEntity` or `ServiceStorageSummaryDoctrineEntity`?
        }

        foreach ( $uow->getScheduledEntityDeletions() as $entity ) {
            // Should I run the computation here?
            // Which entity should I be listening to? `ServiceDoctrineEntity` or `ServiceStorageSummaryDoctrineEntity`?
        }
    }
}
```

But I am not sure how to proceed on this:

1. Am I right on using Event Subscriber?
2. Am I right to listen on `onFlush` event
3. Which entity should I listed to:

   (a) `ServiceDoctrine` entity and loop through each storage devices?

   (b) or to `ServiceStorageDevicesDoctrineEntity` but doesn't that mean that the computation logic will run for each of the storage device changes?

Answer (score 1):

> Am I right on using Event Subscriber?

Yes. If you want to perform some logic after a certain event occured, you are in the right place to do it.

An `EventSubscriber` gives you more flexibility as you can listen to multiple Doctrine events (where an `EventListener` is usually tied to a specific event)

> Am I right to listen on onFlush event

The `onFlush` event happens after all the entities change sets have been computed.

Since you want to *update* data of a related entity, I suggest you to listen to the following events :

- `prePersist`
- `preUpdate`
- `preRemove`

> Which entity should I listed to

Listening to `ServiceStorageSummaryDoctrineEntity` would mean that you could perform some operations whenever *this entity* is being changed. But since you never update this entity manually, your event will never be triggered.

What you want to do instead is watching for changes whenever a `ServiceStorageDevicesDoctrineEntity` has been changed.

Your EventListener could look like this :

```
class ServiceStorageDevicesEventListener implements EventSubscriber {
    public function getSubscribedEvents() {
        return array(
            Events::prePersist,
            Events::preUpdate,
            Events::preRemove,
        );
    }

    public function prePersist(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
    {
        $entity = $args->getObject();

        // don't perform operations for other entities
        if (!$entity instanceof ServiceStorageDevicesDoctrineEntity) {
           return;
        }

        // update your related entity here, ex:
        $entity->getServiceStorageDevices()->getServiceStorageSummary()->setTotalValue(10);
    }

    public function preUpdate(PreUpdateEventArgs $args)
    {
        // ...
    }

    public function preRemove(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: i was able to solve my problem by keeping `onFlush` event so far I am not getting any issue, but if I will have one I'll try to use your solution.